# Docker create image with all installed applications

Tags: image, docker

How can I "mirror" my whole system to a Docker image on an automated way? I wouldn't like to create only a base-image, but all my installed applications to image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some example in "[Create a base image](https://docs.docker.com/articles/baseimages/)".
You have two options:

- use a distro command like [`debootstrap`](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap), which can install a distro base system into a subdirectory of another, already installed system.
  But that is not exactly what you want since it wouldn't copy your own host distro content.
- use the SCRATCH image, and copy the files you want in it.

Comment: `debootstrap` generates an image with 0 B virtual size. These scripts build only base images: https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/contrib

Comment: I agree. Which is why I mentioned that it wasn't what you were looking for.

Comment: True, but that way, you have total control